# How to copy postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I have USB mounted SATA drive with some Postgresql databases on it (hard drive contains installed ArchLinux) and would like to move them to current system. Unfortunately I cannot boot from that drive and dump the SQL files. Can someone tell is it hard to move physical files and directories or some other method how I could migrate those databases.
Maybe there is a way to create a symbolic link for current postgresql to use that hard drive as well?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28926/1822

Comment: just copy files to local drive and start pg -D path_to PGDATA ?..

Comment: Which is the default data directory? /var/lib/postgres/data ?

Comment: I edited /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service and found that data directory indeed is /var/lib/postgres/data. Will try my luck to moving those files